# Padding a string with ASCII control characters - Objective C

Tags: c#, ios, objective-c

Ok, so I have some C#:

```
ASCIIEncoding textConverter = new ASCIIEncoding();

int padLen = 16 - (pwd1.TextLength % 16);
int totalWidth = pwd1.TextLength + padLen;
byte[] password = textConverter.GetBytes(pwd1.Text.PadRight(totalWidth, (char)padLen));

PaddedPassword.Text = Convert.ToBase64String(password);
```

All this does is take a string (pwd.Text) and pad it out to a multiple of 16 using the total number of missing characters as the character Decimal. Then it converts it to base 64 and puts it into a text box. Lets say the example password is test12, the output would be:

dGVzdDEyCgoKCgoKCgoKCg==

I want to replicate this functionality in Objective C. I've tried hardcoding the character to 10 as a test but I believe that this is using UTF-8 character codes rather then ASCII:

```
NSString * Password = @"test12";

int padding = 16 - ([Password length] % 16);

char ch [] = {10};

for(int i=0;i<padding;i++)
{
    Password = [Password stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char*)ch]];
}

Password = [Password stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@""];


NSLog(@"Password after padding: %@", Password);

NSLog(@"Padding: %d", padding);

NSString *base64EncodedString = [[Password dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];

NSLog(@"Encoded Padded PWD: %@", base64EncodedString);
```

The output of which is:

dGVzdDEy

So it's not far off the final output, what I can't work out is how to pad it out using the required length as a character.

Any help would be much appreciated, it's probably (hopefully) quite simple but I just can't work out how to accomplish it.

Thanks!

Adam

Comment: Are you looking for NSASCIIStringEncoding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so this was staring me straight in the face. Bit silly really, but still. What I ended up doing was this:

```
NSString * Password = @"test12";

int padding = 16 - ([Password length] % 16);

int asciiCode = padding;

for(int i=0;i<padding;i++)
{
    Password = [Password stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c", asciiCode]];
}

NSLog(@"Password after padding: %@", Password);

NSLog(@"Padding: %d", padding);

NSString *base64EncodedString = [[Password dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];
NSLog(@"Encoded Padded PWD: %@", base64EncodedString);
```

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of the for loop is to add \n to the string.

After the loop you do

```
Password = [Password stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@""];
```

That replaces the added \n with nothing = removes them.

BTW: It would be easier to have a string literal with 15 \n and then add the substring with the length of padding to the source string:

```
int padding = 16 - ([Password length] % 16);
password = [password appendString:[@"\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n" substringToIndex:padding]];
```